# Rank of a matrix if one of the diagonal elements is $0$ during elementary row operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, gaussian-elimination

I'm required to find the rank of a square matrix A of dimension $m * m$. While doing elementary row operations I encountered a $0$ at a diagonal position. I tried all the possible row exchanges, but none of these could get a nonzero number at that location.

At this step what can one tell about the rank of the matrix? Is it $0$ or $m-1$ or something else? And what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question correctly, but one $0$ in a matrix does not imply anything about its rank.

Comment: This zero came about when performing elementary row operations as I said in the description. It also seems impossible to get rid of that zero by further row operations, as mentioned. So I wondered if this means the rank of the matrix is 0 or m-1 or anything like that.

Comment: One zero does not mean anything regarding the rank of the matrix, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{K})$ be defined as

\begin{align*}
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} && B = I_3
\end{align*}

Matrix $A$ is obtained from $B$ by performing row operations, but yet $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(B) = 3$.

But there is something of interest. If the question was

> What does it mean for the rank of a matrix if we obtain a zero at the diagonal in the row reduced form?

And from this you can conclude that (for example) if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $m$ is the number of zeros that you find in this situation, then $\text{rank}(A) = n -m$.